# How to update and publish a template change in MovableType

Tags: templates, publish, movabletype

Total MovableType NOOB question here.
I have a client that has me updating a MovableType site. I have updated a global template that controls all the blogs within the site but I can't seem to get my code published after saving the template.

If I login or out of the system I can see my changes to the file but it just doesn't publish. Do I have to republish the entire site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to republish the *entire* site, it depends where this template is used and whether it is included and/or cached. For example if it is only used in an index or module template, you can rebuild that template alone (it will have a "Save and publish" button in the editor if this is the case). But if it's site-wide, or you don't know and want to be on the safe side, then yes rebuilding everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to re-publish your site / blog / whatever. Movable Type uses 'static publishing', meaning that your template won't be used until the site will be re-published.

look for the small icon that looks like a refresh / recycle

Answer (score 1):

If it is a global template and your changes aren't reflected right away, then it means that your blogs are using the 'static' publishing method and you will have to go to each and every blog that uses the global template you've changed and rebuild it.

The rebuilding icon is the rounded arrows one from inside the movable type admin right corner.

If you have a lot of blogs and don't want to do the rebuilding manually, you may like to consider installing the 'PowerRebuild' plugin from: http://plugins.movalog.com/powerrebuild/

This plugin would allow you to rebuild multiple blogs at once, without having to go inside each and every blog to rebuild it.